# Linear Maps, Null Space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $S$ and $T$ are linear maps from $V$ to $\Bbb F$ that have the same null space. Show that there exists a constant $c\in\Bbb F$ such that $S = cT.$

Comment: This is really just an exercise in writing the vector space as a union of cosets:  i.e. every vector looks like $\lambda v+w$ for some unique $v$ outside the null space and $w$ in the null space. From that you don't need finite dimensional, inner product, orthogonality, bases, or anything complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a "simple solution" which just uses the definition of null space.

**Case 1)** If $T=0$, then $S=0$ (because $S$ and $T$ have the same null space) and thus $S=cT$ for any $c\in F$.

**Case 2)** If $T\neq 0$, then there exists $x_0\in V$ such that $T(x_0)\neq 0$. Furthermore, for all $x\in V$,

$$\begin{align*}
0&=T(x_0)T(x)-T(x_0)T(x)\\
&=T(T(x_0)x-T(x)x_0)&&\text{(linearity of $T$)}\\
&=S(T(x_0)x-T(x)x_0)&&\text{($S$ and $T$ have the same null space)}\\
&=T(x_0)S(x)-T(x)S(x_0)&&\text{(linearity of $S$)}.
\end{align*}$$
It follows that

$$S(x)=\frac{S(x_0)}{T(x_0)}T(x)\quad\forall \ x\in V$$
and thus $S=cT$ where $c=S(x_0)/T(x_0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $S,T$ are linear functionals, we know that their null spaces have codimension $1$. This means that they are only nonzero on the orthogonal complement of their null spaces and that the orthogonal complement has dimension $1$.

Denote $U$ to be the orthogonal complement of the null space in $V$. Let $x$ be a basis element for $U$. Then $Sx = a$ and $Tx = b$ for some $a,b\in \Bbb F$ nonzero. Or equivalently, $Tx = \frac{b}{a}Sx$.

Do you see how to proceed?

If $V$ is not necessarily a Hilbert space, then you can adjust the terminology so that $U = V/\text{null}(S)$ and proceed from there.

Comment: Sorry, but is there another way to explain it? I haven't learned orthogonal complement yet. Sorry!

Comment: No worries! You can use the rank nullity theorem instead. $S$ is a map from $V$ to $\Bbb  F$ so its rank is $1$ and its nullity is $n-1$ (if $n$ is the dimension of $V$). Same goes for $T$. It also has rank $1$. If they have the same null space, then they also are non zero on the same subspace of $V$ with dimension $1$. Then just proceed as I did with a basis for that subspace.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $V$ is finite dimensional with dimension $n$, and that $S$ and $T$ are non-zero:

Let $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{n-1}\}$ be a basis for the common nullspace of $S$ and $T$ (how do we know the dimension of this subspace?).  Extend this basis by one element so that $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{n-1},v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$.  Any vector $v \in V$ can be written in the form $v = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i$.   We note that
$$
S\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i S(v_i) = a_n S(v_n)
$$
Similarly, $T(v) = a_n T(v_n)$.

Conclude that $S(v) = \frac{S(v_n)}{T(v_n)}T(v)$ for all $v \in V$.

The proof is similar for the infinite dimensional case, but we no longer use "$n$" in our indexing, and rely on the notion of codimension rather than the rank-nullity theorem, hence Cameron's more generalized answer.